# Edit a file from the arg list by search pattern

Tags: vim

I would like to be able to edit `Foo.cs` by partial name without using `:prev` or `:first` et cetera.

```
Foo.cs Bar.cs [Baz.c]s Qux.cs
```

I have tried `:arge F*` and Vim says: `No match`. I have also tried `:arge *F*`. How can I navigate directly to `Foo` using part of its name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the buffer is already opened, you can just type parts of the name using `:b`.

```
:ls
  1 #h   "Foo.cs"                       Line 1
  2  h   "Bar.cs"                       Line 1
  3 %h   "Baz.c"                        Line 1
  4  a   "Qux.cs"                       Line 1
:b F
:ls
  1 %a   "Foo.cs"                       Line 1
  2  h   "Bar.cs"                       Line 1
  3 #h   "Baz.c"                        Line 1
  4  h + "Qux.cs"                       Line 1
```